# Published using capistrano, is it possible to know which version is running using GIT? or anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I pushed code to my server using capistrano (using git also).

I then made changes on my laptop, but haven't sinced published to the server.

I want to know which git version I pushed to the server so I can rollback to that version.

Is this possible?

I know I should have used tags but kinda late for that, hoping I can figure out the version I pushed to my server, so I can rollback to that version or at least diff from that version to the current built to see what has changed since then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Capistrano should have put a REVISION file under `#{your_app}/current` on the server, with the deployed commit's SHA:

So something like:

```
     git diff `ssh your_user@your_server "cat /path/to/your/app/current/REVISION" `
```

should get you the appropriate diff.

Comment: let me check, I thought that folder under current was more of a datetime  than a sha hash.

Comment: The REVISION file on my deploy is empty. Does anyone know why can that happen?

Comment: The REVISION file seems to be empty when i use the 'copy' strategy.          `set :scm, :none  
  set :repository, "."  
  set :deploy_via, :copy  
  set :copy_exclude, [".git", "log", "tmp", "bundle"]`

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can check your reflog.

```
git reflog
```

But you should be tagging when you release.

Hope this helps

Comment: what should I be looking for?

Comment: progit.org/book is a good start and will get you going well enough to use tags.

Answer (score -1):

```
git fetch
git log origin/master -1
```

`fetch` synchronizes with your server and `log origin/master` shows the log of your server's git repo instead of your local repo. The `-1` tells it to only show the last commit. This will show the commit hash and message of the last commit on your server's repo.

If your server is listed in your remotes as something other than `origin` or your server is using a branch other than `master`, you'll have to change that. But "origin" and "master" are the defaults and are standard convention if you haven't changed it.

`<subjective>`
Unless you're explicitly versioning your software (like when creating a gem, for example), it's not necessary to add a tag every time you deploy your app. This would quickly become unwieldy. With git, a commit hash can be used just like a tag if it's ever needed.`</subjective>`

Comment: not sure if this is relevant, but the server that I publish to is the same server that has the bare git repo.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether it's a bare repo. Are you saying this didn't work?

Comment: Current version on git server is not necessarily the last deployed version.